# Codeigniter: $this->load->database(); return blank page

Tags: mysql, database, codeigniter

I use latest CI version 2.2.0.

When i put the code `$this->load->database();` on controller, the correspond view page will return blank. Therefore, I can't connect to the database.

p/s:

- I have right config to database and installed mysql, mysqli php extension
- The same code work fine on local computer, it won't work on hosting.

Comment: What are you expecting to see?

Comment: Read the document: http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/database/

Answer (score 0):

Actually, this problem is caused by using PHP version > 5.3. I fixed that

Comment: I mean just use Codeigniter with PHP 5.3 only. the other version will cause bugs

Answer (score 0):

I had exactly the same problem. It worked when I changed the dbdriver in "database.php" config from mysql to mysqli.

It should look like:

$db['default']['dbdriver'] = 'mysqli';